# Which of these sets is a subspace of F?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

Let $F = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. I need to check which of these sets are subspaces of $F$:

1. $F_1 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x$ is bounded}\}$,
2. $F_2 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x$ is convergent}\}$,
3. $F_3 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x$ is a zero sequence}\}$,
4. $F_4 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x_n = x_m$ for $n \ge m$}\}$,
5. $F_5 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x$ has exactly one limit point}\}$,
6. $F_6 := \{ x \in F:\ \text{$x$ is unbounded}\}$.

How do I show that $F_1,\dots,F_6$ are subspaces of $F$?

I know the definition of a subspaces, but I'm afraid I don't know how to apply it on, for example, $F_1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $F_k$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ you should verify that $F_k$ is a **non empty set** and **any linear combination of two elements of $F_k$ remains in $F_k$**.

Let's show an example:

Clearly $F_1$ is a non empty set since the zero sequence is bounded.

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ two bounded sequences so there's $M,N$ such that
$$|x_n|\leq M\quad\text{and}\quad |y_n|\leq N\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
and let $a,b\in \mathbb R$ so
$$|ax_n+by_n|\leq |a||x_n|+|b||y_n|\leq |a|M+|b|N\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
so the sequence $(ax_n+by_n)$ is bounded and then $F_1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$.

Comment: This helped me a lot, I did the others on my own and feel like I understood everything of this. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Is any linear combination of bounded sequences, a bounded sequence? If yes, $F_1$ is a linear subspace.

Notice that $F_6$ is not a linear subspace...